# How can I upgrade PostgreSQL while using PgQ queue system?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, upgrade, postgresql-9.5

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3 and PgQ 3.2.6 for about two years and now it's time to upgrade. I found out that upgrading PostgreSQL is fairy simple. Just install new Postgres version and then:

```
sudo pg_dropcluster 9.5 main --stop
sudo pg_upgradecluster 9.5 main
sudo pg_dropcluster 9.5 main
```

But I wonder, how the fact that I have working PgQ on top of my DB server affects this process? It looks like there is no related information in the Internet.